# Donde almacenar contraseñas

Tags: java, tomcat

estoy haciendo una API con Java y sera desplegada en un servidor Tomcat y me gustaría saber cual es la mejor forma de almacenar contraseñas como es por ejemplo el acceso a bbdd o la clave con la que voy a encriptar una serie de datos.

Un saludo

Comment: Tienes varias opciones una es guardan el nombre de la base de datos y contraseña en un fichero de properties que vaya en función del entorno. Tipo properties_des, properties_pre, properties_pro. Y el des,pre,pro lo pones en una variables que le pasas al tomcat. Otra opción es configurar el acceso a base de datos con JNDI, está opción es más segura ya que no tienes que poner esos datos en ficheros de código fuente, y sólo los podrá ver quien tenga acceso a la máquina.